# Failure to find com.atlassian:atlassian-localhost:jar:1.1.0

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, repository

I'm trying to add the maven dependency **atlassian-mail** in the pom.xml file.

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>atlassian</id>
            <name>Atlassian Repository</name>
            <url>https://maven.atlassian.com/content/repositories/atlassian-public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>atlassian-mail</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\jmvmarti.m2\repository\com\atlassian\atlassian-localhost\1.1.0\atlassian-localhost-1.1.0.jar' 027_mycoolwebapp        Build path  Build Path Problem

When I execute **pom.xml** in as *Maven build...* defining the Goals as *clean package* (I have read somewhere that's could solve the problem, but does not work). I get the following error message:

```
<pre>
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------< com.luv2code:mycoolwebapp >----------------------
[INFO] Building mycoolwebapp Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.atlassian:atlassian-localhost:jar:1.1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.991 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-01-10T10:45:31-03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project mycoolwebapp: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.luv2code:mycoolwebapp:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.atlassian:atlassian-localhost:jar:1.1.0 in https://maven.atlassian.com/content/repositories/atlassian-public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of atlassian has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem too.

As you may or may not be aware, Atlassian-localhost-1.1.0.jar does not appear anywhere in the atlassian repository url you've quoted. So the error at least makes sense as to why its throwing it. For something as big as not including dependant jar files in their own repository, I'm baffled why they've done this (or should I say, not done this?).

The only work around I can suggest that worked for me, is to manually download the jar from an external source:
https://nexus.xebialabs.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/atlassian/atlassian-localhost/1.1.0/

and manually pull it into your local repository:

(C:\Users\jmvmarti.m2\repository\com\atlassian\atlassian-localhost)

After that, update your Maven project once more and it should be fine then.